# classicthesis + unnumbered chapters/sections: problem with linking

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, classicthesis, scrreprt, unnumbered-sections

I'm finalizing my PhD thesis and there seems to be a problem when using the classicthesis package together with unnumbered chapters/sections (I use the scrreprt class, but the problem might be more generic). Specifically, when using classicthesis, the links to anything unnumbered, both in PDF bookmarks and in the TOC, work incorrectly - they always lead to the beginning of the PDF.  Let me show you a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\addchap{XXX}
\addchap{YYY}
\addchap{QQQ}
\addchap{ZZZ}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Now, whenever I click on any unnumbered chapter in TOC/bookmarks, I always go to XXX. Once you remove classicthesis, the problem goes away.

I tried to also use a more manual way of including unnumbered chapters (with addcontentsline, etc.), and it has the same problem.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Thanks for the comment! I did more digging and there was also some other external factor that influenced the issue. However, the problem was also related to the ordering of loading classicthesis and hyperref. The current order in the code below is OK, swapping the order resulted in the problem.

Comment: Your minimal example works for me, TOC and PDF viewer bookmarks take me to the right chapters. texlive-2020-34, classicthesis 4.6. It also works at overleaf.com.

Comment: Thanks, it did help with debugging!

Comment: Mac, do you know what caused the problem?